# Bus connection from Jesenik to Vidnava, Czech Republic

Tags: public-transport, buses, poland, czech-republic

I'm planning a trip from Wroclaw to Prague by public transport and want to stop in Vidnava (a Czech town close to the Polish border). I figured out most parts of the way, but I'm struggling with the connection between Jesenik and Vidnava.

What I found out so far is, that the closest I can get to Vidnava by train on the Czech side is Jesenik and [according to Rome2rio there is a bus connection from there](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Jesen%C3%ADk/Vidnava). I think I checked it before, but now the [link](http://www.osnado.cz/pages/jizdni-rady/) returns a 404 error page.

I've spent quite some time searching the web for any definite information about this connection, but without luck. Does anyone know, which line it is, if it's still in operation, where I can find a timetable and how to buy tickets?

**Note:** I might decide to do the trip in the opposite direction instead (Prague to Wroclaw), but I think it shouldn't make a difference concerning the original question as buses (if they run) will most likely go both directions.

Comment: Jesenik is closer to Prague than Vidnava. Do you want to stop there because you specifically want to visit Vidnava or because you think it's one the Wroclaw-Prague route?

Comment: Yes, I want to visit Vidnava and planned the rest of the trip around it. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I just wanted to add, that apparently Jesenik is not the closest train station (in operation), you can actually reach Velká Kraš just 3 km out of Vidnava.

Comment: Velka Kras is even easier to get from, as there's a direct bus every hour which only takes 5 minutes. Or you could just walk :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bus runs between these two cities a few times per day, operated by `ARRIVA MORAVA a.s.`. You can find the exact schedule on the [IDOS - Trains + Buses](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/vlakyautobusy/spojeni/) website:

[image]

For some reason it's impossible to buy the tickets online, but you shouldn't have any issues getting one on the spot from the driver. The price is 35`CZK` per leg.

Comment: You usually can't buy tickets online for local buses, everyone buys them from the driver. But you can buy tickets online for long distance buses (like the one from Jeseník to Prague).